# Address of stack variable keeps changing

Tags: c++, c

I wrote following sample piece of code, just to print the address of a local variable.
Since the variable `a` is in a known stack frame, so I thought its address is fixed.
But when I run the compiled binary multiple times, it print out different addresses.
I wonder why the address of `a` keeps changing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  printf("address: %p\n", &a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559761/why-are-the-virtual-memory-regions-for-the-same-program-different-on-every-run/559775#559775

Comment: For security reasons. See [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)